# Regex to get data from a sentence

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to write a regex that matches different patterns in order to extract data from a text, like in the following example:

```
City A is 10 minutes away from City B and 6 minutes from City C.
```

I want to get the first city (City A) then each city that is linked to it and its respective distance.

In this case, I need to have this information:

```
City A
City B => 10
City C => 6
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:

The number of cities is not fixed. The first city can be linked to 1 or N cities.

Example with 1 city:

```
City A is 10 minutes away from City B.
```

Example with 3:

```
City A is 10 minutes away from City B, 6 minutes from City C and 8 minutes from City D.
```

Comment: You haven't given enough information on the problem for a reasonable answer: does your string always have 3 cities? Is it always `away from` and then `from`?

Comment: Regex should work fine if format of the data is consistent.

Comment: Craigy, the number of cities won't always be the same. It can be from 1 to N. And yes, for the first city it is "away from" and for the rest of them it is "from".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this

```
 #  "\\G(?:(?:^(?<TimeBase>)\\s*City\\s+(?<CityBase>\\w+))|(?:(?:\\s+(?:is|and)|\\s*,)\\s+(?<TimeExtra>\\d+)\\s+minutes(?:\\s+away)?\\s+from\\s+City\\s+(?<CityExtra>\\w+)))"

 \G  
 (?:
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?<TimeBase> )
           \s* City \s+ 
           (?<CityBase> \w+ )
      )
   |  
      (?:
           (?:
                \s+ 
                (?: is | and )
             |  \s* , 
           )
           \s+ 

           (?<TimeExtra> \d+ )
           \s+ minutes 
           (?: \s+ away )?
           \s+ from \s+ City \s+ 
           (?<CityExtra> \w+ )
      )
 )
```

Comment: A breathtaking abuse of regular expressions.

Comment: just what am I seeing here >_<

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse a certain text containing fixed word combinations like those i your example, than yes, it's suitable for regex filtering. Otherwise you'd better follow the proposal above and use grammar and lexer.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly it's possible; anything can be done.

A better question is: "Is there a better solution for this problem?"

Maybe you'd want to think about a simple grammar, a lexer and parser.

You could try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) or JavaCC if regex doesn't cut it.

Comment: Can't imagine why this was voted down.

Comment: regex and parsers have different capabilities; the former is a finite automaton and the latter a push-down automaton. this problem is perfectly suited to regex; using pda is overkill, unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: I know what both are.  "perfectly suited"?  That wasn't clear until the 3rd comment above by Vitor.  This answer isn't wrong; your vote is just your opinion.

Comment: may be you answered before the OP's edits/clarifications. i stand behind my downvote. a lexer instead of regex would be reasonable (and still a finite automaton), but bringing in a parser is questionable. i'll agree to disagree.

Comment: ps: for contrast see @nikita's answer which addresses the different problem domains

Comment: He's not saying anything different from me.  Note: "better follow the proposal above and use grammar."  Like I said, regularity wasn't stated when I answered.  Answers will help that more than comments - free advice to you.

Comment: the "better follow" is conditional. i was just expressing my opinion on your answer and a comment is considered polite rather than just a silent downvote. i do sympathize with the fact that regularity wasn't stated upfront but not enough to remove the downvote.

Comment: I don't care.  Let it go.